# Shouldn't we fuse "planet" and "planets" tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

I recently noticed that we have both [planet](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planet) and [planets](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planets) tags. I may be wrong, but aren't both of them used in the same ways? Shouldn't we fuse them or label them as synonyms?
I think this is an important tag as "planets" is the seventh more popular tag on this site (and it would be fourth is we fuse them).

Answer (score 5):

Yes, and the singular form should have precedence, compare with other popular tags such as "star" or "black-hole"

Comment: Merge complete, this answer can be accepted